# Deploy java app in Chef cookbook

Tags: ruby, rubygems, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am already using application cookbook to deploy and install my java application. I tried it on my own.

```
application "saymetrix" do
path "/usr/local"
owner "chef"
group "chef"
end
```

And for the above code i get following error.

```
Error executing action `deploy` on resource 'application[saymetrix]'
================================================================================
NameError
---------
Cannot find a resource for saymetrix on ubuntu version 12.04


Cookbook Trace:
---------------
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/application/providers/default.rb:82:in `before_deploy'
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/application/providers/default.rb:27:in `block in class_from_file'
```

I don't get how to resolve this?

Comment: Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the [application_java](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/application_java) cookbook.

you need to add these in the `metadata.rb` of your *saymatrix* cookbook:

```
depends 'application'
depends 'application_java'
```

And add necessary details at least including `repository` and deployment target like `tomcat`. You can find the section *Usage* of the example here: [application_java](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/application_java)